# Expansion of lower incomplete gamma function $\gamma(s,x)$ for $s < 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, gamma-function

The lower incomplete gamma function for positive $s$ is defined by the integral
$$
\gamma(s,x)=\int_0^{x} t^{s-1} e^{-t} dt.
$$
Taylor expansion of the exponential function and term by term integration give the following expansion
$$
\gamma(s,x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{n+s}}{n! (n+s)}
$$
Here $\gamma(s,x)$ can be analytically continued for complex $s$ except some singular points. Does the above expansion still hold in this case? Especially I'd like to know if the relation holds for $s < 0$. Each term of the series is well defined for $s < 0$. Is this enough to ensure the validity of the relation or does it need more arguments?

Comment: You need more arguments.  If you could show that the sum is an analytic function of $s$ for $s \neq 0, -1, -2, \ldots$ then the equality would hold for $s \neq 0, -1, -2, \ldots$ by analytic continuation.  For such an argument one could probably make use of the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.7.E3 we have the series expansion 
$$\Gamma(s,x) = \Gamma(s) - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{n+s}}{n! (n+s)}, \qquad s \ne 0, -1, -2, \ldots 
$$
Combine this with the relation for the gamma functions (http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2.E3)
$$\gamma(s,x) + \Gamma(s,x) = \Gamma(s).$$
Therefore the series expansions remains valid for all non-integer $s<0$ 
$$
\gamma(s,x) =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{n+s}}{n! (n+s)}, \qquad s \ne 0, -1, -2, \ldots 
$$
Another route is via Tricomi's entire incomplete gamma function $\gamma^{*}$, see http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.7.E1.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Ok, the expansion is right for complex $s$. I understand the $\gamma^*$ approach. By the way, do you have any comment about my last question?

Comment: I guess with _validity_ you mean (well-)defined. This is necessary but you still need the convergence of the sum.