# How to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-x} \,dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am trying to solve this improper integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-x} \,dx$.

First I replace de infinity by a another variable $y$, so:
$\int_{0}^{y} x^{-x} \,dx = \int_{0}^{y} e^{\ln(x^{-x})}\,dx = \int_{0}^{y} e^{-x\ln(x)}\,dx = \int_{0}^{y} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x\ln(x))^{n}}{n!}\,dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!} \int_{0}^{y} (x\ln(x))^n\, dx$.

Solving $\int (x\ln(x))^n\,dx$:

1. Substitute $u=\ln(x) \implies \int u^ne^{(n+1)n}\,du $
2. Substitute $v=u^{n+1} \implies \frac{1}{n+1}\int e^{(n+1)v^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}\,dv$
3. Substitute $w=(n+1)^{(n+1)}v  \implies \int e^{(n+1)v^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}\,dv = (n+1)^{-n-1}\int e^{w^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}\,dw$
4. $\int e^{w^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}\,dw = -(n+1)(-1)^n \operatorname{\Gamma}(n+1,-w^{\frac{1}{n+1}})$
5. Undo substitutions, $\int (x\ln(x))^n\,dx = \dfrac{\left(n+1\right)^{-n-1}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(n+1,-\left(n+1\right)\ln\left(x\right)\right)}{\left(-1\right)^n}$
6. $\int_{0}^{y} (x\ln(x))^n\, dx  \implies \dfrac{\left(n+1\right)^{-n-1}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(n+1,-\left(n+1\right)\ln\left(x\right)\right)}{\left(-1\right)^n}  \Big|_0^y$, when $x=0$, the incomplete gamma function will be evalueate between plus infinity and plus infinity so, $\int_{0}^{y} (x\ln(x))^n\, dx =  \dfrac{\left(n+1\right)^{-n-1}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(n+1,-\left(n+1\right)\ln\left(y\right)\right)}{\left(-1\right)^n}$
7. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!} \int_{0}^{y} (x\ln(x))^n\, dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(n+1,-\left(n+1\right)\ln\left(y\right)\right)}{n!(n+1)^{n+1}} =   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{Q\left(n,\ -n\ln\left(y\right)\right)}{n^n}$.

Where $Q$ is the normalized or regularized incomplete gamma function

But what's happen when $y \to \infty$? The incomplete gamma function will be evaluated between zero and minus infinity, is it valid? Is there another way to find this value? Because de the improper integral converges.

Comment: $1.9954$, approximately.  There is no reason to think it has a closed form.

Comment: You might find it easier to think about if you instead substitute $v=-u=-\ln x$.

Comment: Have you considered wolfram-alpha?

Comment: Yes, but no response. The sum is correct, the problem is when y goes to infinity. The values will oscillate between infinity and minus infinity, but in the end, the sum will converge.

Comment: I recommend watching [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/lHi53QereHA) Explains it quite nicely.

Though the video shows it how to solve the integral from 0 to 1 but the way would be same

Answer (score 3):

See this answer/my question:

> [Area under $x^{-x}$ over its real domain. What is another non-integral form of $$\int_{\Bbb R^+}x^{-x}dx$$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4135449/area-under-x-x-over-its-real-domain-what-is-another-non-integral-form-of)

In summary, here are the results:

$$\int_{\Bbb R^+}x^{-x}dx =\\ \lim_{x\to \infty}\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{Q(n,-nx)}{n^n}= \\\lim_{b,n\to \infty}\frac bn \\\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{bk}{n}\right)^{-\left(\frac{bk}{n}\right)}=\\ \sum_{n\ge1}n^{-n}-\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n\ge1}(-x)^n\  _1\mathrm{\tilde F}_1(n,n+1,nx) =\\ \sum_{n\ge 1}n^{-n}-\lim_{x\to \infty}\sum_{n\ge1}\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{(-x)^n(nx)^k}{(k+n)k!n!}= \\\lim_{x\to \infty}\sum_{n\ge 1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k e^{nx} n^{k-n}x^k}{k!}$$

Here is [**proof**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+Q%28x%2C-3x%29%2Fx%5Ex+from+1+to+1000) of the main result and @Nikos Bagis’s representation:

$$\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{1}{t^t}\textrm{d}t=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^n}-1+\int^{1}_{0}\frac{1}{t^{t^{t^{ \ldots}}}}\textrm{d}t $$

Where appears the [$\,_1
\mathrm {\tilde F}_1(a,b,z) $ Confluent Regularized Hypergeometric function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedHypergeometricFunction.html) , [Regularized Incomplete Gamma function $Q(a,z)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedGammaFunction.html), and [infinite tetration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108288/infinite-tetration-convergence-radius)

Let’s see if we can use @Rounak Sarkar’s method from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4168572/integral-over-domain-of-infinite-tetration-of-x-over-extended-domain-from-0-to) to find a sum only answer.

*Let me work on this to actually get some new results*.

If you want here is a [Mellin Transform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) representation:

$$\int_0^\infty x^{a-1-x}dx=\int_0^\infty x^{a-1}x^{-x} dx\implies \int_0^\infty x^{-x}dx=\mathcal{M}\{ x^{-x}\}(1)$$

I do not use [Ramunajun’s Master Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem) much, but let’s try it:

$$\mathcal{M}\{f(x)\}(s)=\Gamma(s) y(-s), f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n y(n)x^n}{n!} $$

So we need to find the “alternating” Exponential Generating function for $x^{-x}$

According to this theorem, then:

$$\int_0^\infty x^{-x} dx=\mathcal{M}\{ x^{-x}\}(1) =y(-1),x^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n y(n) x^n}{n!}$$

So how do we find $y(n)$?

Here is how to find $y(n)$:
The coefficients are just a Taylor series for $x^{-x}$ at $x=1$ which is just [OEIS A176118](https://oeis.org/A176118)

Therefore: $y(n)=(-1)^n \text A176118(n)$

And *experimentally*:

$$\int_0^\infty x^{-x} dx \mathop=^\text{natural}_\text{extension}-\text A176118(-1) $$

But this is stretching the definition. Maybe we can use an nth derivative formula to find a closed form for the nth derivative? Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Thanks, for me the most strange thing is if you see the graph of the partial sum, the amplitude of series diverges when x goes to infinity. (Correct me if I am wrong) The sum comes from infinity to minus infinity and in the end, it converges to a value. My question is: is it correct?

Comment: Though the partial sums do alternate and even become absurdly large in magnitude, the answer does indeed converge. You just need an infinite number of terms in the series in order for it to converge in the first place. If this is unsatisfying, one should note the following:

Comment: The function $\dfrac{2}{x^2}$ is *strictly* greater than $\dfrac{1}{x^x}$ on the interval $(0,\infty)$. Since we know that $\int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{x^x} \textrm{d}x$ is finite, if we want to check if $\int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{x} \textrm{d}x$ is finite, then we must check whether $\int_1^\infty \dfrac{2}{x^2} \textrm{d}x$ is finite. If it is, then since $\int_1^\infty \dfrac{2}{x^2} \textrm{d}x$ is strictly greater than $\int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{x^x} \textrm{d}x$, we may conclude that $\int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{x^x} \textrm{d}x$ is finite, and thus so is $\int_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{x^x} \textrm{d}x$.

Comment: In any case, $\int_1^\infty \dfrac{2}{x^2} \textrm{d}x = 2$, hence $\int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{x^x} \textrm{d}x < 2$. Sorry for the sloppy "proof," but I think it's ample justification that the integral is not infinite. Hope this helped!

Comment: @ArjunVyavaharkar Thanks. Your proof would make a great answer.

Comment: It seems like the partial sums must be much larger than the value of $x$ in $Q(n,-n x)$

Comment: The question remains, the series of infinity values could converge, only because it could be derived from an improper converge integral?

Comment: Technically yes. Although a series can be defined as the limit of a sum when the limit goes to infinity, the limit and the actual answer don't always agree. For example, if you were to add every natural number in an infinite series, the limit would blow up to infinity, even though the series itself is equal to $-\dfrac{1}{12}$. The same thing applies in this scenario: The $\limsup$ goes to $+\infty$ while the $\liminf$ goes to $-\infty$. However, the series itself nicely converges to $~1.995...$

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash Excellent answer btw! Just a few minor tweaks to make the expressions a bit less fuzzy.

Comment: @ArjunVyavaharkar All that was done is a previous question, but thanks for the edits and comment.

Comment: The problem is that sum is a sum of infinity values, not finite numbers.

Comment: Well, it's the same problem as $\infty-\infty$: It's in *indeterminate form*. However, that doesn't necessarily mean we can't calculate the sum, because we can, although doing so would require a limit so that we don't have to handle the difference between two infinite quantities.

Comment: @ArjunVyavaharkar Do you think [Ramanujan’s Master theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem) can be used? It is in the answer, but the generating function is not found. Thanks.

Comment: @TymaGaidash could you recomend me a good book for study  Ramunajun’s Master Theorem?

Comment: I was think if we decompose $Q$ function and interchange the sum and integral it will be $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!(n+1)^{(n+1)}}dx$, but $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!(n+1)^{(n+1)}}$ is what function?

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash Sadly no, I'm not sure if RMT would be appropriate. However, if you find anything, please let us know!

Comment: You could potentially use Feynman's technique to parameterize the integral and solve for a class of integrals instead.

Comment: I trying to use Lambert W function because $-\frac{W(-x)}{x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ (n+1)^nx^n}{(n+1)!} $ but no success.

Comment: @GuilhermeNamen I have also tried finding closed forms [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317227/closed-form-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac%ce%b3na-bnnknc-with-the-l) and a few other posts, but no luck. I recommend the wikipedia link in the answer for the Master Theorem since I am new to the formula, so I do not know many books on it, but maybe try finding a copy of Ramanujan’s notes?

Comment: @TymaGaidash, thanks. My best guess is it could be some special Lambert $W$ function. We need to try some transformation of this function to create a Taylor expansion to fit this series.

Comment: This is an old answer

Answer (score 2):

Using the known identities
$$\int\limits_0^1\ln^n z\,\text dz = (-1)^n n!,\tag1$$
$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^k \dfrac{a^m}{m!}=e^a\, \dfrac{\Gamma(k+1,a)}{\Gamma(k+1)},\tag2$$
one can get
$$I_1(a)=\int\limits_0^a x^{-x}\text dx 
= a \int\limits_0^1 (ay)^{-ay} \text dy
= a\int\limits_0^1 e^{-ay\ln a} e^{-ay\ln y}\text dy$$
$$= \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \dfrac{\ln^m a}{m!}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{m+n} \dfrac {a^{m+n+1}}{n!}\int\limits_0^1  y^{m+n}\ln^n y\,\text dy$$
$$= \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \dfrac{\ln^m a}{m!}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{m+n} \dfrac {a^{m+n+1}}{n!(m+n+1)^{n+1}}\int\limits_0^1 \ln^n (y^{m+n+1})\,\text dy^{m+n+1}$$
$$= \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \dfrac{\ln^m a}{m!}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{m+n} \dfrac {a^{m+n+1}}{n!(m+n+1)^{n+1}}\cdot(-1)^n n!$$
$$= \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^m\dfrac{\ln^m a}{m!}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {a^{m+n}}{(m+n)^n}
= \sum\limits_{s=1}^\infty \dfrac{a^s}{s^s}\sum\limits_{m=0}^{s-1} 
\dfrac{(-s\ln a)^m}{m!}$$
$$I_1(a)= \sum\limits_{s=1}^\infty \dfrac{\Gamma(s,-s \ln a)}{s^s\Gamma(s)}.\tag3$$

On the other hand,

$$I_2(a)=\int\limits_a^\infty x^{-x}\text dx 
= a \int\limits_0^\infty (a(1+y))^{-a-ay}\text dy
= a^{1-a}\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{a^{-ay}}{(1+y)^a} (1+y)^{-ay}\,\text dy.$$
Let $\;z=a^{-ay} = e^{-(a\ln a)y},\;$ then $\;y=-\dfrac{\ln z}{a\ln a},\;$
$$(1+y)^{-ay}=\left(1-\dfrac{\log_a z}a\right)^{\log_a z}
=1 - \dfrac{(z-1)^2}{a\ln^2a}+\dfrac{(z-1)^3(2a\ln a-1)}{2a^2\ln^3a} +\dots 
=\dfrac{(2a^2 \ln^3a-4a\ln a+1) + z(10a\ln a-3) + z^2 (3-8a\ln a) + z^3(2a\ln a-1)}{2a^2\ln^3 a}+\dots,$$

Taking in account the integral
$$\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{a^{-kay}}{(1+y)^a} \,\text dy
=a^{ka}\operatorname E_a(ka\ln a),\tag4$$
one can get
$$\begin{align}
&I_2(a)\approx \dfrac1{2a\ln^3 a}\big((2a^2\ln^3a-4a\ln a+1) E_a(a\ln a) + a^a(10a\ln a-3) E_a(2 a\ln a)\\[4pt]
& - a^{2a}(8\ln a-3) E_a(3a\ln a) + a^{3a}(2a\ln a-1) E_a(4a\ln a)\big).
\end{align}\tag5$$
Approximation $(5)$ is not too accurate (accuracy $\;1.5\%\;$ for $\;a=e^2\;$), because only three terms of the primary series was used. However, it shows the effectiveness of the used approach.

If $\;a=e^3,\;$ then $I_1(a)\approx 1.99545\,59575\,00138\,00041\,87246\,96764\,22,$

$I_2(a)\approx 1.69475\cdot10^{-27},$

$\;I_1(a)+I_2(a)\approx
1.99545\,59575\,00138\,00041\,87246\,98458\,97.$

Numeric value is
$I=1.99545\,59575\,00138\,00041\,87246\,98452\,72.$

Easily to see that the second integral increases the result accuracy.

$\color{green}{\mathbf{Edition\ of\ 23.12.21.}}$

The alternative way is

$$I_2(a)=\int\limits_a^\infty x^{-x}\text dx 
= a \int\limits_0^\infty (a(1+y))^{-a-ay}\text dy
= a^{1-a}\int\limits_0^\infty a^{-ay}(1+y)^{-a-ay}\,\text dy.$$
Let $\;z=a^{-ay} = e^{-(a\ln a)y},\;$ then $\;y=-\dfrac{\ln z}{a\ln a},\;$
$$I_2(a)= \dfrac1{a^a\ln a}\int\limits_0^1 \left(1-\dfrac{\log_a z}a\right)^{-a+\log_a z}\text dz 
=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_n\ln^n z,$$
$$I_2(a) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n n! c_n,\tag6$$
where
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_n y^n = \dfrac 1{a^a\ln a} \left(1-\dfrac y{a \ln a}\right)^{\large-a+\frac y{\ln a}}.\tag7$$

By the direct numeric calculations,
$$I_2(e^3)\approx 1.68850\,13010\,68575\,08677\,67860\,60236\,26323\,88582\cdot10^{-27}.$$
Calculations by $(6)-(7)$ by $20$-term model give
$$I_2(e^3)\approx 1.68850\,13010\,38888\,76584\cdot 10^{-27},$$
i.e. ten additional correct digits of the result.