# Is the improper integral between plus infinity and plus infinity necessarily equal to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Is the improper integral $\int_{\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \,dx $ necessary equals zero?
The question is simple, but if the function diverges when it goes to infinity?

In my opinion, it is not a valid improper integral when the function diverges. But if we define this object as $\lim_{a \to +\infty} \int_{a}^{a} f(x) \,dx$ it is zero.

Comment: How you define it is essential. You could equally define it as $\lim_{a\to\infty\\b\to\infty}\int_b^a$ which could cause issues if $f$ diverged really badly

Comment: Some hints in [Improper integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Improper_integrals): "the improper integral is the limit of proper integrals as one endpoint of the interval of integration approaches either a specified real number, or ∞, or −∞. In more complicated cases, limits are required at both endpoints, or at interior points."

Comment: There is another way to define this as $\lim_{a \to +\infty} \lim_{b \to +\infty} \int_{a}^b f(x)dx$, and emerges another question if the interchange limits are different or diverges or one converges and another not?

Comment: Exactly yeah. Unless the function was sufficiently nice in general this is not necessarily definable in a useful way

Comment: the notation $\int_\infty^\infty f(x)\,dx$ is simply meaningless

Comment: In my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323761/how-to-calculate-int-0-infty-x-x-dx) I used this in the 6º step, and it works. At that time I don´t care about it. For me, the integration between two same values is not a valid Reimann Integral because you can not create a partition in a point. But if you define it as an improper integral like my previous comment, you can create a partition that tends to a point.

Answer (score 4):

Since the improper integral $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ is defined as
$$
\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx \overset{\text{def}}{=} 
\lim_{b \to \infty}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx,
$$
it is natural to define $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ as
$$
\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx \overset{\text{def}}{=}
\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{a}^{\infty}
f(x)
\,dx.
$$
With this definition, if $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ exists and is finite for all sufficiently large $a$, then for all $A > 0$,
$$
\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx - \int_{a+A}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx
=
\int_{a}^{a+A}f(x)\,dx
\to
0
\text{ as }
a \to \infty.
$$
Hence, if $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ exists and is finite for all sufficiently large $a$, then
$$
\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx = 0.
$$

If, on the other hand, $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx = \pm\infty$ for all sufficiently large $a$, then
$$
\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx
=
\lim_{a \to \infty}\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx
=
\lim_{a \to \infty} \pm\infty
=
\pm\infty.
$$

Finally, if $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ diverges for all $a$ without going to $\pm\infty$, then $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ is not defined.

------ Edit ------

When interchanging the limits in the above definition, a sign change occurs. To fix this, we could instead define $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ as
$$
\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx \overset{\text{def}}{=} 
\lim_{a \to \infty}
\lim_{b \to \infty}
(-1)^{[b < a]}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx
$$
where
$$
[b < a] \overset{\text{def}}{=} \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }b < a,\\
0 & \text{if }b \ge a.
\end{cases}
$$
This has the effect of undoing the sign-change since
$$
(-1)^{[b<a]}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx
=
\begin{cases}
\int_{b}^{a}f(x)\,dx & \text{ if }b < a,\\
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx & \text{ if }b \ge a,
\end{cases}
$$
which means
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{b \to \infty}\lim_{a \to \infty}
(-1)^{[b<a]}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx
&=
\lim_{b \to \infty}\lim_{a \to \infty}
-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx
\\&=
\lim_{b \to \infty}\lim_{a \to \infty}
\int_{b}^{a}f(x)\,dx
\\&=
\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: This is sufficient to prove that the incomplete gamma function goes to zero when x tends to infinity. Thanks a lot. But if we define the improper integral as $\lim_{a \to +\infty}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon} f(x)dx$ the only condition is that for all $f(x)$ such that $x > a$ the function must be differentiable.

Comment: In my opinion, you are right, but what is missing is that we can not interchange the limit operation in this case, as I did in my previous comment.

Comment: @GuilhermeNamen I've edited my answer giving an alternate definition which enables one to interchange the limits by removing the sign-change that occured when doing so using the old definition.

Comment: An excellent answer, thanks a lot. I was afraid that it could not be possible to use the improper gamma function when x goes to infinity.